# Situation when the people asking a question is not the best person to choose the best answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I wonder if there are "superuser rights" that allow hi-rep users to change the accepted answer ? Because, for question about "best pratice" for instance, it's obviously not the one asking the question that will be the best person to choose the right answer...

Comment: If someone can explain me the downvote, I maybe will not make the same mistake again later... ;-)

Comment: Here on Meta downvotes are a bit different from the main site. It is often used more like a agree/disagree poll. So don't take it too serious. It may just mean, that somebody thinks you proposed to add this as a feature and thinks it's a bad idea.

Comment: Weird! Because 0 can mean : "Nobody cares" and "+10/-10" (big controversial topic). Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't: [it's been suggested periodically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3669/149432) on the network-wide meta discussion site, but it's always roundly rejected.

All questions on Stack Exchange need to be verifiable in principle: the asker should be able to take an answer and see if it works for them. That's the answer that they'll generally accept. It might not be the most optimal solution or the one that the community agrees with, but the asker is always going to be in a better position to know what's going to work for them because they're the ones in a position to try it.

So the idea is that there are two different metrics people should be looking at:

- What the community thinks is the right answer
- What the asker felt helped him or her the most

The first is marked by the answer with the most votes. The second is marked by the acceptance check mark.

Comment: Excellent clarification between community / asker Mark.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The only person that can accept an answer (or change the accepted answer) is the question poster.

All "accepted answer" means is that **"this answer helped me the most"**, nothing more and nothing else. It doesn't have to be best practise or even good practise, it just has to help the questioner out of his or her hole.

Comment: Seems a bit in contradiction with their motto "Let's make the internet a better place for valuable information"

Comment: @Pierre - The most upvoted answer would be the one most people believe is the best one. That's a better place already.